# How can we do the MVC with ADO.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a task to work for MVC using ADO.NET.Can we do this using normal ADO.NET?If possible some helpful links.

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Do you mean ... MVC using _ASP.NET_ ...?  For sure ADO.NET seems an odd match here.

Comment: I am also not agree with ADO.NET also.But need to follow my client requirements.

Comment: @Jai Ganesh Some times people like to use *straight ADO.NET* in applications instead of *ORM tools like NH, EF*.. because of scalability, learning curve etc. Most of the MVC samples uses EF for db operations but you can use *ADO.NET (dataset/datareader)* there. I would recommend to use a *repository pattern*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, it not possible with `raw` ADO.NET without using some kind of containers for data like DataSet.

The reason is providing model from action method and querying this model from inside view has different scope. View accesses model after action method is exit. Consider following code sample:

```
public ActionResult SomeAdoNetAccess(int id, string name) 
{
   ...
   using(var command = CreateSampleCommand()) 
   {
      command.Parameters["@Id"].Value = id;
      ..
      using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
      {
            return View(reader);
      }
   } 
}
```

When view tries to access reader, reader is already disposed. So some kind of container is required.

For other things you can pass command parameter values as action parameters, and use ViewState for passing additional data to view without using typed models. This is not a problem but it needs more effort rather than regular models.

Comment: thanks .Can you please provide me a sample App?

Comment: Sorry don't have one :( That was just ad hoc typed example.

Comment: Thanks to all for providing a good way to achive my task.